# How to invoke Action on Component Controller from VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

**@Adrian Larson:** I can not use `Action="{!clearSelect}"` thats because I already have method that get the Id that I have selected on VFP controller, unless is there a way to capture Id in the Component Controller?

```
public void SelectId()
{        
    String arId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('arId');
    SelectId  = arId;           
}
```

EDIT:

After reading and I found this:

So in the Component I have added the following line:

```
<apex:attribute name="clearAction" 
    description="" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/>
```

in my VFP I have updated my component:

```
<c:example_component currentId="{!exampleId}" clearAction="{!clearSelect}" />
```

I have defined the void method `clearSelect` on Component controller but I'm not sure how to invoke this action from VFP.

I like to invoke the `clearSelect` method when the user clicks on the radiobutton

```
  <apex:actionsupport action="{!SelectId}" event="onclick" >  
    <input type="radio" name="arRadioButton"   />                    
    <apex:param name="arId" value="{!ar.Id}"></apex:param>
  </apex:actionsupport>
```

END EDIT

How to invoke Action on Component Controller from VFP to Component page? and I have laid down some lines of code and its very basic but the point here is to get the concept of how the event is fired. in this particular case, if the user clicks on the radiobutton i want to fire an event on the component page.

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="vfp_Controller" showheader="true" sidebar="true">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="arpageblock"  > 

     <apex:pageblocktable id="ar_pageblocktabel" value="{!AllRules}" var="ar">
         <apex:column headervalue="Action"  >                    
           <apex:actionsupport action="{!SelectId}" event="onclick" >  
                        <input type="radio" name="arRadioButton"   />                    
                        <apex:param name="arId" value="{!ar.Id}"></apex:param>
</apex:param>  
                    </apex:actionsupport>                            
                </apex:column>  

                <apex:column headervalue="Name" style="width:16%;">
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!ar.Name}">
                </apex:outputfield></apex:column>

            </apex:pageblocktable>
      </div>  

          <c:example_component currentId="{!exampleId}" />

</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Component Page:

```
<apex:component controller="ExampleComponentController">
  <apex:attribute name="currentId" type="Id" assignTo="{!myId}" required="true" description="Example Id for display." />
  <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block">{!myUser.Name}</apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: what do you mean by an 'event on the component'? a Javascript event? Or do you want an action function on the component to execute against the component's controller

Comment: yes I meant to say `Action` invoked on the component's controller

Comment: did you read: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50008/passing-data-from-page-controller-to-component-controller ?

Comment: I just went through and the action is more about passing a data but mine is more like invoking action on the component controller; if you think my answer is in the link which I could not able to catch please paste here.

Comment: if you want to call VF cpage controller action indide the component then i have a quick workaround for you. Pass a javascript method name in component and from javascript method call the Action function now in your component call this Javascript function. it willl do your work. Cheers...

Comment: can you point me to the blog that explain little bit more?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication to have VFP cpntroller be aware of component controller and vice-versa;  - the `selectId` action on the VFP controller can invoke the `clearSelect` method on the component controller

Comment: but how can be invoked?.. I do not find any decent example that talks about that

Comment: Use `action="{!clearAction}"`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: I have updated my question please have a look at it

Comment: Your update doesn't seem at all related. You have passed your `ApexPages.Action` into your `Component` with a name of `clearAction`, which you should now be able to use as you would any other action. e.g. `<apex:commandButton action="{!clearAction}" />`

Comment: i'm not sure if you understand what I'm trying to do but just to recap again:, I'm using component in the vfp and in the vfp page i have `radiobutton` as shown in the code and when the user clicks on the radio button I'm capturing which Id the user has selected and so far so good, everything is working as excepted but the million dollar question is:  when the user select the radio button I want two things to happen 1) select the ID user clicks on 2) invoke action on Component Controller - hope this make sense.

Comment: Hello Nick, Are you able to resolve this issue? Please let us know the solution its very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @ShrivathsKulkarni: unfortunately not! and I have to change my approach and go with different route.